# curl get json data

Tags: node.js, json, linux, curl

I am trying to get data from a server by curl in json format and the command is below:

```
curl -X GET https://api.coinex.com/v1/market/kline?market=BCHBTC&type=1min -H "Accept: application/json"
```

I got the error:

```
{"code": 2, "data": {}, "message": "invalid params"}
```

The command works well in   the following website:

```
https://reqbin.com/req/c-vdhoummp/curl-get-json-example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to surround your URL with single quotes

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.coinex.com/v1/market/kline?market=BCHBTC&type=1min' -H "Accept: application/json"
```